# Is there a library of physical units?

Tags: resource-recommendations, units, si-units

There are some standard units we all understand intuitively such as:

Mass (kg)
Length (metres)
Time (seconds)

From these there are some familiar composite units which are also well understood:

Velocity (m/s)
Force (Newtons = kg m/s^2)
Energy (Joules = kg m^2/s^2)

Then there are some obscure ones such as:

Moment (kg-metres)

And then truly esoteric units that may arise usually in research:

Ex: (m/s)^(1/2) Or kg m^3/s^5 etc...

My question:
———

Is there a library of all known physical units that have appeared in some research paper or experiment/have some meaning attached to them.

Say someone runs into some obscure unit in their research. Can they go this library to find connections with other unusual areas of physics?

I can see this as being useful for making thought experiments in esoteric parts of physics.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97838/discussion-on-question-by-frogeyedpeas-is-there-a-library-of-physical-units).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of lists of units, but no one is maintaining an exhaustive list of every unit that has ever appeared in a published paper. Physicists find more interesting ways to spend their time.